# Proof that sets are equal if Cartesian products are equal.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having some problems with this proof. I have been trying to prove it for the last 2 hours and have not been successful. So can anyone give me some advice? Thank you in advance.

Let $A, B, C, D$ be sets. Suppose $A \neq \emptyset$ and $B \neq \emptyset$, and $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = (C \times D)$.

Prove that $A=B=C=D$.

Comment: As a first step, show that if $A=B$, then $A=B=C=D$.

Comment: Have you been able to show any set inclusions so far?

Comment: You can element chase.  If $x \in A$ and $y\in B$ then $(x,y) \in(A\times B) \subset  (A\times B)\cup (B\times A) = (C\times D)$ so $x \in C$ and $y\in D$.  So $A\subset C$ and $B\subset D$.  Can you continue?  (Hint: $(y,x) \in B\times A\subset (A\times B)\cup (B\times A)$.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila ok, I proved that if $A=B$ then $A = B = C = D$. The next step will be if $A \neq B$?

Comment: @fleablood I will try

Comment: @Sambo yes, but I'm stuck in the middle and don't know how to move forward

Comment: Now simply show that if $A\neq B$, then it is impossible that $(A\times B)\cup(B\times A)$ is itself of the form $C\times D$. In other words, there will be some ordered pair missing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!